# Excel Index Small If with OR statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, formula

=(INDEX(data,SMALL(IF((data,[POSITION]="Manager")*(Data[Bonus]="yes")*(data[relocation]=A1)OR*(data[relocation]=B1,ROW(data[relocation])),ROW(1:1))-1,COLUMN(Data[NAME]))

I've been trying to figure the above formula out for ages but still couldn't get it to work.

All I want is the formula to return me all the names of the managers with a bonus that are willing to relocate to either cities in A1 OR B1.
I'm using Array so it can list as many managers as possible.

I tried to use OR in various nesting but couldn't figure out so I would appreciate any help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
=(INDEX(data,SMALL(IF(AND((data[POSITION]="Manager"),(Data[Bonus]="yes"),OR((data[relocation]=A1),(data[relocation]=B1))),ROW(data[relocation])),ROW(1:1))-1,COLUMN(Data[NAME]))
```

This will identify those people who are Managers AND have a bonus AND (will relocate to A1 OR Relocate to B1)

The syntax for AND() and OR() is that the AND or OR goes at the front of a list of things you want to check.

Even better is to paste the following function at the end of the data table and copy it down.

```
=IF(AND((data[Position]="Manager"),(data[Bonus]="yes"),OR((data[relocation]=$A$1),(data[relocation]=$B$1))),data[NAME],"")
```

It will copy the name into the column if the person fits the criteria you specified but leave it blank if they did not. This will allow you to filter he table on this column and see other data if you need to.

[image: Sheet with formula]

As you want to make use of Index/Small to collate the results, you can change my original formula to:

```
=IF(AND((data[Position]="Manager"),(data[Bonus]="yes"),OR((data[relocation]=$A$1),(data[relocation]=$B$1))),1,0)
```

This will put a 1 in the row of anyone who fits your criteria and a 0 in the row of anyone who doesn't.

Then you can use the Index/small method on THIS data column (which I have called Selected)

```
=INDEX(data,SMALL(IF(data[Selected]>0,ROW(data[Selected])-3),ROW(1:1)),3)
```

[image: Using INDEX/SMALL]

Comment: This would return error, I tried and/or in various locations, simply doesn't work. If I remove the And/Or statements, just do bonus**position*location, it would work. But I need to look into 2 locations not one...

Comment: I have attached a screen shot showing the formula working. As it is now part of the table it has dropped the data[] notation. If you are happy to show part of your actual spreadsheet or a redacted version, I could check the formula for your specific case.

Comment: my conclusion is when you put and/or statement to index/small, it doesn't work. Now, even this would not work =index(data,small(if(and((data[position]="Manager"),(data[bonus]="yes")),row(data[relocation])),row(1:1))-1,column(data[name])) BUT if I use * instead of AND, it would work. Bizarre...

Comment: I built a formula which doesn't use index/small. Mine just returns ONE value (the name of the person), which is why you can't find the Smallest or index it afterwards.

Comment: Yes but I have a huge table with various scenarios that's why an index and small is a must for me - I need to use index/small in my case - there are other stuff I'm trying to get from the table also

Comment: I have updated my solution with a way of adding the INDEX/SMALL capability you requested.